# Is it possible to disable new validators from joining?

Tags: pallet, staking

I am experimenting with the staking pallet on substrate V3.0 and I was trying to disable the functionality that allows new validators from joining.

I would like to keep the staking functionality but just disable new validators from joining if possible.

Looking at the `validate` extrinsic in the staking pallet, I can't see any obvious ways to disable it without changing the source code.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could apply a filter to your runtime which would block users from making a call to the `validate` function.

```
/// Use this filter to block users from calling `validate` in the Staking pallet.
pub struct DontAllowValidate;
impl Contains<Call> for DontAllowValidate {
    fn contains(c: &Call) -> bool {
        !matches!(c, Call::Staking(pallet_staking::Call::register { .. }))
    }
}
```

Then you configure your System pallet to use this filter:

```
impl frame_system::Config for Runtime {
    type BaseCallFilter = DontAllowValidate;
    // -- snip --
}
```

This works for any call, and is how Polkadot and other chains disabled transfers or other kinds of calls in the bootstrapping stages of the network.

Answer (score 2):

The given answer does not work and can easily be circumvented with proxy, multi-sig, batch, or any other type of call wrapping.

The better way to do this would be to set `MaxValidatorCount` to 0. Then no one can call the `validate` transaction.