# When using pallet-assets in another pallet: how to make pallet-assets calls private?

Tags: pallet, extrinsic, assets, call

I'm using pallet-assets for my pallet, let's say custom-assets. In `custom_assets::transfer` I make some additional business logic and call `pallet_assets::transfer`. I want to make pallet_assets calls private so that logic wouldn't fail because no one can call `pallet_assets::transfer` with my custom asset directly.

What I intend to do: just modify pallet-assets and move extrinsic `pallet_assets::transfer` from `#[pallet::call] impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {` to  `impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {`  - but this removes any info about weights, and maybe has another consequences.

Is it a good idea to do so? what can I do with weights? are there any other consequences? and maybe there is another better option to forbid direct `pallet_assets::transfer` extrinsic call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a call filter in your runtime which prevents any calls to your pallet:

See a similar question here: [Is it possible to disable new validators from joining?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/140/is-it-possible-to-disable-new-validators-from-joining/141#141)

Something like:

```
/// Use this filter to block users from calling any function in Assets pallet.
pub struct DontAllowAssets;
impl Contains<Call> for DontAllowAssets {
    fn contains(c: &Call) -> bool {
        match c {
            Call::Assets(_) => false,
            _ => true,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's an example in the wild that helped me adapting it: https://github.com/Phala-Network/khala-parachain/blob/main/runtime/phala/src/lib.rs#L289-L297